# How to deploy a python WSGI Flask Application using nginx without manually running uwsgi?

Tags: nginx

So, I am right now at this point. The webpage can be accessed without any errors and without using any specific port. Example: www.my-example.com.

But, this works only when I run the command "uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:4567 --protocol=http -w wsgi" in my server.

How to automate this app deployment through nginx?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to automatically start uWSGI, restart it if it fails, and log stderr/stdout:

```
[program:app]

# emulates a virtualenv
directory    = /srv/app/
environment  = PATH="/srv/app/virtualenv/bin"

command      = /srv/app/virtualenv/bin/uwsgi --ini /srv/app/config/uwsgi.ini
autostart    = true
autorestart  = true

user         = app-user
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this?

Comment: @GokilaDorai: Supervisor is a daemon that is launched when your server boots. It autostarts uWSGI and restarts it if it fails, so you don't need to run anything manually.